# Embed SVG in another SVG, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm appending a lot of blank SVGs like a mosaic to an svg called 'background', like so:

```
var baseView = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect"); 
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"id",id);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"x",xOff);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"y",yOff);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', bD);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', bD);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'red');
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");
document.getElementById("background").appendChild(baseView);
```

Where background is defined:

```
<svg id="background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
```

I'm then trying to embed a further SVG within the baseView SVG:

```
var trunkView = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect'); 
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"id",trunkID);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"x",xInset);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"y",yInset);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', (bD/2 + branchWidth));
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', trunkWidth);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");
baseView.appendChild(trunkView);
```

I've also tried:

```
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(branchView);
```

When I append directly to the 'background' svg the child 'trunkView' appends correctly and is visible, but not when it is embedded within 'baseView'. Per the browser, it says it is there but is not displaying. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the specs of 'rect' elements, you'll see this :

```
Content model:
Any number of the following elements, in any order:
animation elements — ‘animate’, ‘animateColor’, ‘animateMotion’, ‘animateTransform’, ‘set’
descriptive elements — ‘desc’, ‘metadata’, ‘title’
```

So 'rect' elements are not allowed as content of 'rect' elements, which would explain why it doesn't render.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#RectElement

EDIT:

To group element, you can use a 'g' element. Like this:

```js
var baseView = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"rect"); 
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"id",5);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"x",5);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"y",5);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'red');
baseView.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");
document.getElementById("group").appendChild(baseView);
var trunkView = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect'); 
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"id",10);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"x",40);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"y",40);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 100);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 100);
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
trunkView.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");
document.getElementById("group").appendChild(trunkView);
```

```html
<svg id="background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="group"></g>
</svg>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: There’s no way to embed children? I need to be able to animate rotate the parent, and would consider making the parent a regular div, but want to up the performance.

Comment: see my edit, you can use 'g' elements which are made for grouping other svg elements.